# Spring Authorization Server and support for JWT Authorization Grant

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

Does anyone know if there any plans for implementing JWT Authoriation Grant in Spring Authorization Server as specified in RFC here? https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523.html#section-2.1

I did it myself by implementing bunch of converters and providers and customized OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer but ideally I would like not need to do it by hand.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not supported. There is an issue in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/546

Go ahead and upvote the issue on github to give it more momentum.